# How can I write dynamic query?

Tags: 7, database

Can anybody suggest to me how I can write a dynamic query in Drupal for the below MySQL query.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
select * from cap_pas where pas_uid not in
  (select pas_uid from cap_boat_to_pas)
```

Comment: For documentation relating to this see https://www.drupal.org/dynamic-queries and https://www.drupal.org/node/310086

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many similar questions on Drupal Answers.

```php
$subquery = db_select('cap_boat_to_pas', 'cp')
  ->fields('cp', array('pas_uid'));

$query = db_select('cap_pas', 'cp')
  ->fields('cp')
  ->condition('cp.pas_uid', $subquery, 'NOT IN');

results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

**Note**: to write this in a single query (by using joins), take a look at [leftJoin()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AleftJoin/7.x).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any possibility of writing this in a single query by using joins??

Comment: Yes. you can. I didn't try it. You can take a look on [leftJoin()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AleftJoin/7.x)